# SQL Server database for c# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am new at programming and I want to make an app which uses a SQL Server database. Most important feature of this database must be usable for every computer which has the app installed.

I mean, when I give this app's setup file to another person, this person should be install my app without installing SQL Server program, extra things etc. I don't know it is possible.

I created a database with "SQL Server Object Explorer" inside of  "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" but when I tried to add new connection, server name was empty. So I didn't import a database to my project.

So how/where can I create and import a database ?

Comment: you should look into hosting in regards to having an actual server that sits remotely.. then you create a Sql User account for your application also distributing local copies of a database to so many users is not a very optimal thing.. do some googling on how to setup remote database for windows application.. please do some more research..

Comment: If your application *uses* SQL Server, then the user that wishes to use your application **must** either install SQL Server locally on his machine, or be able to connect to a server instance of SQL Server somewhere in his company network. There's no *magic* way around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a local SQL database with your application, that is: data is not shared between devices or users, you'll want something like SQLite which is designed for embedding in distributed applications.

To use it you need to link against the binary and include the binary in your application package. Or, you can use the SQLite team's native C# SQLite library. See here: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I never heard SQLite and I think, I found what I need. When I research about SQLite, I found another solution, I am not sure. Has SQL Server Compact got same purposes like SQLite? If answer is yes, I will try both of them for my project.

Comment: Yes, it looks like SQL Server Compact is Microsoft's solution to embedded SQL databases. It should work similarly.